# Is the REST API active in Italy?

Tags: paypal

I just wanted to know if I can use the REST API with an Italian account. I couldn't find any information about.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use REST api with an italian account, the link posted by KevinG does not state that you cannot.
I used it last year to implement Expresscheckout and it was working. Be sure to check if you need to be PCI or PCI-DSS compliant.

For more information you care read this faq https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/#non-US-dev

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API from Italy and you have a full access to all features in your sandbox account. In live account you have some limitations (no Direct credit cards processing!).

more info here (login in your developer account first): https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accountStatus

Answer (score -1):

Currently the REST API is not available in Italy. This link will take you the the most current information regarding the REST API and supported countries:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments